# Gunicorn не отправляет сообщения telegram через telebot в django

Tags: python, django, telegram, бот, gunicorn

Проект на django. Импортирован модуль telebot. 
Реализован метод отправки:

```
token = '<<API_TOKEN>>'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
chatId = <<сhat.id>>
bot.send_message(chatId, text)
```

При запуске тестового сервера: python3 manage.py runserver - все работает и сообщения отправляются.
Но когда я запускаю gunicorn: gunicorn app.wsgi - сообщения не уходят.

Никак не могу решить этот вопрос, буду очень благодарен если кто-то подскажет!

---

Gunicorn запускается, но теперь при попытке входа в админку выда`т ошибку:

> 'MEDIA' object has no attribute 'render_styles'

Подскажите пожалуйста, что за проблема такая. Заранее очень благодарен, а то уже три дня сижу на этим!

Comment: проверьте настроки ginicorn. может вообще не запускается. и логи приложите

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Gunicorn запускается когда запускаю его уже из директории со своим проектом. 
Cначала cd /path/to/project, а потом source /path/to/project/bin/activate